# How to pass a variable in form action url in vuejs

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, environment-variables, action

I am trying to pass a variable url in form action but couldn't do so with the following code:

```
<form action="${url}/auth/login_student" method="POST">
....</form>
```

**EDIT:**
And in script tag

```
<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return{
        url: process.env.VUE_APP_URL
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I am importing the URL from `.env` which is 2 folders above this file in hirerachy
but it is showing the process.env.VUE_APP_URL is undefined

My `.env` file code:

```
VUE_APP_URL=http://localhost:5000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) to set `action` to a JavaScript expression. You can then use a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```html
<form :action="`${url}/auth/login_student`" method="POST">
      ^        ^                         ^
```

Comment: Thankyou it worked, but following this I am having another issue with environment variables check edit for details.

Comment: You should ask it as a new question.